# codeigniter .htaccess code not loading css, images

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the htaccess provided by codeigniter in their website.
Everything works file, but when i use a `/` after the url, everything gets messed up.
say my domain is `www.example.com/mycontroller` this will work fine but `www.example.com/mycontroller/` makes every thing messed up, no style no image and all that.

I solved the issue by using `base_url()` in front of the links for stylesheet and images etc. But isnt there any other way so that I dont have to go through every image and link to add `base_url()`.

The .htaccess file contains

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: `base_url` sounds like the best way to do it. It's modifiable and extensible.

Answer (score 2):

You should allow files and folders to pass

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

And yes, you should add `base_url`, otherwise your application is less portable and maintenance becomes a nightmare

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if the request points to a file or a directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

If you don't have some realy good reasons you can link relative to the base directory for images or css files.