# Codeigniter css error loading images

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, codeigniter

I've been messing around because when i look at the page it says that he cant load up the image but there are no errors in debugger so its probably a framework error or htacess. This happens after i create my view news witch i accept a param in url (the 4th).

[image: this is the error image]

my htacess

```
ReWriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|assets|robots\.txt)
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I fixed the issue using a htacess rule
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839727/codeigniter-htaccess-code-not-loading-css-images

Comment: You can just remove the dot, and in src you would get absolute url counting from project root.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its not getting the full URL.. Give the total image URL along with the domain name like

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/assets/images/uploads/uploads/b.pn‌​g
```

Comment: yes it is, im using base_url before because that load is on upload folder file that held the images when you create a new, so basicly i use the base_url + the path for acess it and its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your base url example on config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://loaclhost/youyproject/';
```

Or If have domain some thing like

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';
```

Then autoload url helper config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

And then try using like

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/uploads/uploads/b.pn‌​g');?>" />
```

Make sure assets folder out side of application

```
application

assets

system

index.php
```

Comment: Nah i did it already before, the problem here is not that (i print with the base url)s